# Open modal with materialize on event

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-cli, materialize

I use angular2 and materialize in a project.

Materialize is documented for oppenning a modal (dialog/popup) on button click only. It's ae attribut in the button tag that trigger the modal oppenning.

I've done some research and I didi't find how to open on from an event triggered in the Typescript file.

Does anyone have done this before ? How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Could you please provide examples you tried? The materialize library you are using? Maybe a plunker with a simple component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% Sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to trigger a function when an event fires in Angular you need an Eventemitter: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

```
something: boolean = false;

@Output()
somethingChanged= new EventEmitter();
```

When you trigger the event is up to you. For example like this.

```
doSomething(){
this.something = true;
this.someThingChanged.emit(this.something);}
```

Now you bind the attribute to the boolean that is emitted.

```
<button (somethingChanged) = "attributeIWantToBind" > </button>
```

Comment: I found the solution before but yes this is it :)